# Is there a way to reproduce currentColor with var(--current-color)?

Tags: css, css-variables

I don't use `currentColor` very often but when I do, it's extremely useful.

So I've been a little excited about the arrival of **CSS Variables**.

Let's take a traffic light.

**N.B.** Please take it on trust from me that **Japanese traffic lights** go red to amber to blue. I know it's hard to believe. *I know the blue light looks sort-of green.* But it isn't, it's blue.

```css
div {
float: left;
width: 200px;
}

div div {
float: none;
}

.top {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.middle {
color: rgb(255,227,0);
}

.bottom {
color: rgb(63,255,63);
}

.jp .bottom {
color: rgb(0,255,191);
}

.light {
text-align: center;
}

.light::before {
content: '';
display: block;
margin: 6px auto 0;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk">
<h2>UK Traffic Lights</h2>
<div class="top light">Red</div>
<div class="middle light">Amber</div>
<div class="bottom light">Green</div>
</div>

<div class="jp">
<h2>JP Traffic Lights</h2>
<div class="top light">Red</div>
<div class="middle light">Amber</div>
<div class="bottom light">Blue</div>
</div>
```

Now, the clever thing about

```
background-color: currentColor;
```

is that it just reads whatever the current value for `color` is and uses that.

By contrast...

```
background-color: var(--current-color);
```

That can't reference the current value of another style declaration, can it?

So, you'd need to set up 4 variables (just like you need to declare `color:` 4 times in the styles above):

```
.top {
--color-top: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.middle {
--color-middle: rgb(255,227,0);
}

.bottom {
--color-bottom: rgb(63,255,63);
}

.jp .bottom {
--color-bottom-jp: rgb(0,255,191);
}
```

And *then*... you need to reference *each of those* different variables later on. Which means a different `background-color` declaration for each variable:

```
.top::before {
color: var(--color-top);
background-color: var(--color-top);
}

.middle::before {
color: var(--color-middle);
background-color: var(--color-middle);
}

.bottom::before {
color: var(--color-bottom);
background-color: var(--color-bottom);
}

.jp .bottom::before {
color: var(--color-bottom-jp);
background-color: var(--color-bottom-jp);
}
```

**Really?!**

That can't be right. Have I missed something?

Is there no way to reproduce `currentColor` with `var(--current-color)` ?

*Is there no way for CSS variables to represent the current value of another style declaration?*

Comment: The problem is `custom properties` are not really variables, 
the value assigned doesn't change depending on any other condition as happend in other languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can set a CSS custom property instead of setting directly the `color` property, and use it for `color` and `background-color`.

```css
/* Set global variable inside the :root scop */
:root {
  --color-top: rgb(255,0,0);
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div div {
  float: none;
}

/* Set the local --color variable, according to your need */
.top {
  --color: var(--color-top);
}

.middle {
  --color: rgb(255,227,0);
}

.bottom {
  --color: rgb(63,255,63);
}

.jp .bottom {
 --color: rgb(0,255,191);
}

.light {
  color: var(--color);
  text-align: center;
}

.light::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 6px auto 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="uk">
<h2>UK Traffic Lights</h2>
<div class="top light">Red</div>
<div class="middle light">Amber</div>
<div class="bottom light">Green</div>
</div>

<div class="jp">
<h2>JP Traffic Lights</h2>
<div class="top light">Red</div>
<div class="middle light">Amber</div>
<div class="bottom light">Blue</div>
</div>
```

I do not really understand why you are not using `background-color: currentColor`, because it works well in your own example.

Comment: Got it! Thank you @tzi - I see what I was missing. A named CSS Custom Property can hold _different values in different contexts_ without rewriting the values it holds in other contexts. So rather than create an individual custom property (`--color-top`, `--color-middle` etc.) for each context (`.top`, `.middle` etc.) I only need to state what value the custom property `--color` holds in each specific context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SASS (which is compiled into css), then you can use SASS variables. The code will look like :

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

more informations on the [SASS official website](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: That's the same issue, isn't it? What's the difference between `$primary-color: #333;` & `color: $primary-color;` in SASS and `--primary-color: #333;` & `color: var(--primary-color);` in CSS? I think they are the same, aren't they?

Comment: No, because SASS will compile this into CSS with no color var. It will do all the work for you but it'll still be CSS withought var in the end.

Comment: @Rounin you are right. CSS preprocessors had variables before CSS supported it naively. \Relisora please check http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables - your answer isn't accurate.

Comment: I did not know this about CSS, it looks pretty new and will only work on 63% of users ends. Still looks like a very useful tool, thank's for taking it to me