# Is it possible to self reference to current computed attribute using CSS?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less, css-variables

One of the downsides of using variables in CSS is repeating the code
For example If I had 10 different color and I want to change them by hovering I have to define 10 variables in :root and then write 10 different times the same code like this

```
:root {
    --color-1: ..
    --color-2: ..
    ...
}

#item1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(var(--color-1), 0.5);
}

#item2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(var(--color-2), 0.5);
}

...
```

Is it possible to write something like this without repeating the code?
It means reference the current value, whatever it is right now

```
 #item1 {
   background-color: var(--color-1);
 }

 #item2 {
   background-color: var(--color-2);
 }

.item:hover {
    background-color: rgba(@self-background-color, 0.5);
}
```

- I'm aware people using CSS preprocessors to not repeat the code themselves

Comment: Quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395237/is-there-a-way-to-reproduce-currentcolor-with-var-current-color, I think?

Comment: No there is not.